# Swift : deinit is not calling on back button action

Tags: ios, swift

In objective -C on back button dealloc method gets called. Anything similar to that in swift ?

Answer (score 5):

As you seem to understand, `deinit` is the equivalent of `dealloc`. If it's not being called, your object is not being destroyed, which means something has a strong reference to it. This is identical in ObjC and Swift. When you remove your last strong reference, `deinit` will be called.

Neither `dealloc` nor `deinit` has anything to do with a "back button action." They are only related to freeing objects, and should generally only perform resource cleanup. If you're relying on them being called in response to a user action, you probably have a design error.

Answer (score 0):

From the Swift Documentation:

A deinitializer is called immediately before a class instance is deallocated. You write deinitializers with the deinit keyword, similar to how intializers are written with the init keyword. Deinitializers are only available on class types.

Typically you don’t need to perform manual clean-up when your instances are deallocated. However, when you are working with your own resources, you might need to perform some additional clean-up yourself. For example, if you create a custom class to open a file and write some data to it, you might need to close the file before the class instance is deallocated.